# How can I view memory usage, thread dump for java programs, from command line?

Tags: java, memory-dump, thread-dump

Is there any known command line tool to ask the JVM to see memory usage and thread dumps of a java program. something like a headless jvisualvm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) to get gc information, [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) to get stack traces and [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jmap.html) to get memory statistics and memory dumps for off-line inspection.

Comment: @KaizenSoze Did you mean jhat? I mentioned jmap, but maybe you think I should add info about it?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> will produce a thread dump and various statistics.

This is documented, along with `kill -QUIT`, [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/).

Answer (score 1):

Look into the official debugger, [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html).  You have to run your java program with a certain flag, but then you should be able to look at a bunch of stuff from the commandline.